# Google Data Studio filter combining two custom fields

Tags: google-analytics, looker-studio

I am trying to join data associated with two custom variables in the same Google Analytics dataset for a filter widget. We have institution names for older data in customVarValue2 and after GA changed the use of custom variables, newer data in Institution. I would like to be able to access all that data (back to October 2011) in one pageview chart and I think I can do that with a calculated field.

I saw on a post in the Data Studio forums that the logical operators don't work so I've been trying to do this with individual lines like so:

```
CASE 
WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(customVarValue2, '.*Denmark.*') THEN 'Denmark!' 
WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(Institution, '.*Denmark.*') THEN 'Denmark!' 
ELSE 'Other' 
END
```

The goal is to end up with one "Denmark!" field in the widget dropdown where all the data is combined from the two custom fields (customVarValue2 and Institution) to cover the whole date range. I can get it to work with one of the variables and it gives me the choice of "Denmark!" and "Other" with the appropriate date range for the custom variables that I used. But when I put both "WHEN" cases in, I only get "Other" showing in the widget dropdown. I would appreciate any advice you can give.

Thanks,
Sandy

Comment: Could you elaborate by providing a publicly editable Google Data Studio Report (additionally, a Google Sheet if it's the data set) of the scenario (using sample data that shows 1) Input values (~10 rows) 2) Expected output 3) An attempt at solving the issue)? It would help users visualise the issue and test out suggestions on a specific use case with objective right / wrong answers. Without a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it would be difficult to pinpoint a suggestion and the issue, e.g. Data Set, Data Source, Report, Fields, Chart

Answer (score 0):

The version below seems to work for me on a different case. Have you checked the case of the custom variable macthes?

> CASE 
>   WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(customVarValue2, '.*Denmark.*') OR REGEXP_MATCH(Institution, '.*Denmark.*') THEN 'Denmark!' 
>   ELSE 'Other' 
>   END

Comment: I'm sorry for the delay in getting back to you, I missed that this had been answered. I'm having the same problem with this as well. In the filter, I'm only getting "Other" and not the choice of "Denmark" and "Other". I checked the case of the values and they are upper case (Denmark, the string is longer on the front end but the wildcards should match). I am getting the full date range.